# How to store Scipy sparse CSR matrix from TfidfVectorizer efficiently and load it?

Tags: python, mongodb, matrix, scikit-learn, scipy

I'm trying to vectorize a set of documents (fit data or corpus) using `TfidfVectorizer()`, and save this result (`scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`) in MongoDB to use it later. To `tfidf.transform()` some data, and then apply `cosine_similarity()`.

The main idea is to reduce the vectorization time by saving these previously vectorized documents, but keeping memory efficiency when inserting the sparse matrix into MongoDB..

However, you can't directly insert the sparse matrix, as it is not a valid data type in MongoDB.

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

fit_data = ['this is some corpus data', 'foo', 'bar']
transform_data = ['this is some other data to transform']

tf = TfidfVectorizer(...)
tf_fitted = tf.fit_transform(fit_data)

...
type(tf_fitted)
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
...
save: tf_fitted --> convert to any valid data type in mongodb (stored) --> to mongodb
load: to mongodb --> reverse conversion

new_tfidf = load the sparse matrix
tf_transformed  = new_tf.transform(transform_data)

cosine_similarity(tf_fitted, tf_transformed).flatten()
```

#### from rickhg12hs comment/question

```py
import pickle
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tf = TfidfVectorizer()
tf_fitted = tf.fit_transform(fit_data)
tf_pickle = pickle.dumps(tf)

# now we load the pickle tf instance
tf_new = pickle.loads(tf_pickle)
tf_new.transform(transform_data)
```

Comment: scipy.sparse` has a specific `save` function, which uses `numpy.savez` format.  You can't meaningfully save sparse matrices without understanding how the matrices themselves are stored in memory.  There isn't a default method for serializing a sparse matrix to a database like Mongodb.

Comment: Please post a *real* [mre], without dots and arrows inside the code!

Comment: You could define a dictionary using the _Compressed Sparse Row_ attributes, like `{"data": tf_fitted.data, "indices": tf_fitted.indices, "indptr": tf_fitted.indptr}` and then use `pymongo` to store these attributes in a MongoDB document.  This document could later be retrieved and the attributes could be used to recreate the `csr_matrix` using `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr))`.  However, don't you really need to store/retrieve `tf`?  A `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` won't have a `transform` method.

Comment: You could store `pickle.dumps(tf)` (a binary string) in MongoDB as long as the document size doesn't exceed 16 MBytes.

Comment: @rickhg12hs this is useful. To answer your question: I want to save the tokenization of certain corpus, to later calculate cosine similarity with the data to be transformed. This last step can be done a day later. Please check out the question again, I added a section from what you said.

Comment: If you don't want to store the corpus `fit_data`, then you could store the `TfidfVectorizer` `tf` (via `pickle`) and the `tf.fit_transform(fit_data)` `tf_fitted` sparse matrix.  Then later, retrieve `tf` and `tf_fitted` and perform `some_new_data_transformed = tf.transform(some_new_data)` and then `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(tf_fitted, some_new_data_transformed)`.